# Google Cloud SDK installer ERROR Download failed: connecting to host

Tags: sdk, cloud, installation, host, platform

I'm trying to download Google Cloud SDK in my computer but during the installation that error occurred:

**Download failed: connecting to host.**

Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: did you solve it? I am having the same issue and i doesn't seem to be a connectivity issue.

Answer (score 10):

This error could also occur if your computer is behind corporate firewall. The easiest solution is to NOT use installer, but download versioned archive using the following link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives, then follow the instructions on the page e.g. for windows run

```
.\google-cloud-sdk\install.bat
```

Comment: We should consider to add proxy setting also,set HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy host>:80
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://<proxy host>:80

Comment: I had `HTTP(S)_PROXY` configured, it was not the issue for me. I had this issue for over 6 weeks and this the obvious troubleshooting steps

Answer (score -1):

When i tried to install it today,i had the same issue,i figured out that it was the antivirus installed in my system which was creating the issue,either disable it for a while or change the settings to give download permission.